# iOS 7 SpriteKit Scrolling Menu?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios7, sprite-kit

I decided to jump into SpriteKit to start working on a game and I'm a little stuck on how I would create a scrolling menu (like Cut the Rope or Angry Birds for example) that would scroll through the various chapters in the game. I know that when I used Cocos2D there was a CCScrollLayer that would take the items (such as images or buttons) for each chapter and then create the scrolling layer but I can't seem to find something similar in SpriteKit. I was thinking that I could probably use a UIScrollView, but not sure if that is the best way to go or if anyone has found anything else that would work for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that using a UIScrollView works well for me. From an SKScene you have access to the parent view; self.view. From the scene's didMoveToView: method you can add a UIScrollView and remove/hide it from the willMoveFromView: method.